# Stand-alone simulation proof: Ideal functions and leakage collection

Tags: provable-security

Are ideal functions and leakage collections the terms of UC security? Why I often see them in a simulation-based proof under stand-alone model? Some papers use the definition in Lindell's *How to simulate it?* while defining ideal functions (sometimes with leakage collections), which really confuse me a lot!